# When will the mandatory minimum mixin be increased?

Tags: hard-fork, ringsize

Currently a minimum mixin of 2 is mandatory.  It is my understanding that the mandatory minimum mixin will be increased to 4 at some point.  When will that happen?

Answer (score 6):

Block 1406997 doesn't come for 341.5 days (as of this writing, Oct 19th, 2016, at block 1161101).  September 25th of 2017 seems a bit...much.  Please correct my errors.

(I would have posted as a comment to the answer above, but my rating on stackoverflow is too low.  You could help by up-voting me, just for trying to be constructive.)

Comment: You are right about the approximate date. More mixin means bigger tx and the main focus for privacy right now is to bring RingCT to hide the amounts & Kovri to hide your IP.

Comment: Have my vote for trying :)

Answer (score 5):

This will happen on version 5, at block height 1406997 on mainnet (it's already happened on testnet).

Comment: Wow, all this time I thought it was 4 mixins already.

Comment: @pl55 4 mixins is not the min but it is the CLI default already

Comment: That's interesting. So one would have to override the default of monero wallet to achieve a mixin=2 or 3?